# How to use asynchronous drivers in akka-streams map vs mapAsync

Tags: scala, couchbase, akka-stream

I have just started using [reactivecouchbase](http://reactivecouchbase.org/) asynchronous database driver but are running into some basic design issues.
In a traditional approch I would limit the pressure I put on the database by limiting the number of connections to it. However with an asynchronous driver I can just swamp the database with new queries?

Where this has become significant is in an example as follows.

Lets say I have two different ways of calling the database.

My function calls to DB:

```
asyncCallDB: Future[DBResponse]
blockingCallDB: DBResponse
```

Now I want to map the db calls over a stream where I can use two different functions:

```
Flow.map()
Flow.mapAsync(numberOfConcurrentCalls)()
```

Now my questions is how would you select to call the database:

```
Flow.map(blockingCallDB) //One call at a time with back preassure
Flow.map(asyncCallDB) //Unlimited calls floods db no back pressure?

Flow.mapAsync(numberOfConcurrentCalls)(blockingCallDB) //Up to numberOfConcurrentCalls at the same time with back pressure
Flow.mapAsync(numberOfConcurrentCalls)(asyncCallDB) //Unlimited calls floods db no back pressure?
```

I feel that my understading is lacking here and would like to understad this type of decission.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between map and mapAsync](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146418/difference-between-map-and-mapasync)

Comment: Are you sure you can call `Flow.mapAsync` with a function returning `DBResponse` instead of `Future[DBResponse]`? According to [Akka API doc](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow@mapAsync%5BT%5D(parallelism:Int)(f:Out=>scala.concurrent.Future%5BT%5D):FlowOps.this.Repr%5BT%5D) this shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReactiveCouchbase uses [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) for communication with Couchbase server(s). As you can [see in the source code](https://github.com/ReactiveCouchbase/ReactiveCouchbase-core/blob/master/driver/src/main/scala/org/reactivecouchbase/Couchbase.scala#L163) it calls `setMaximumConnectionsTotal`, which limits the number of concurrent connections. The actual value depends on what you configured in `couchbase.http.maxTotalConnections`.

There is one `AsyncHttpClient` for each `CouchbaseBucket` you create. So there is a maximum of `maxTotalConnections` connections for each `CouchbaseBucket`.

From [Couchbase documentation on N1QL REST API](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/n1ql/n1ql-rest-api/index.html):

> The REST API runs **synchronously**, so once execution of the statement in
>   the request is started, results are streamed back to the client,
>   terminating when execution of the statement finishes.

So in practice the number of concurrent queries is limited to `maxTotalConnections` for each of your buckets.

Thus, the backpressure on DB is always limited in some way. Either because you set `maxTotalConnections` to a non-negative number, or because your client can't create more connections because of limited RAM or number of file descriptors.

However, it's still possible to create too many `Future`s, so that your client will run out of memory. Whenever you think this may be the case you should probably use `mapAsync`, as mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146418/difference-between-map-and-mapasync), or one of the other techniques mentioned in ["Buffers and working with rate" (Akka documentation)](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.12/scala/stream/stream-rate.html).

There's a [good description of `mapAsync` in the Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.12/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#mapasync):

> Pass incoming elements to a function that return a Future result. **When
>   the future arrives the result is passed downstream. Up to n elements can be processed concurrently**...

Keep in mind that `Flow.mapAsync` won't run anything by itself, it just returns a `Flow` which you have to connect between a `Source` and a `Sink`, then `run`.  [Akka Quick Start Guide](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.12/scala/stream/stream-quickstart.html) describes this in a very comprehensible way.

Comment: Yes but map async only makes sense if you are using a blocking request right?

Comment: @user3139545 Well, you need to run the stream, right? So you need to connect some kind of sink to your flow. The sink won't be processed until your flow produces some results. `Flow.mapAsync` won't do anything by itself, it just returns another `Flow` ([doc](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow@mapAsync[T](parallelism:Int)(f:Out=>scala.concurrent.Future[T]):FlowOps.this.Repr[T])).

Comment: I found a Couchbase documentation fragment which mentions that queries are synchronous indeed: ["The REST API runs synchronously, so once execution of the statement in the request is started, results are streamed back to the client, terminating when execution of the statement finishes."](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/n1ql/n1ql-rest-api/index.html)

Comment: @user3139545 Edited the answer. I hope this is clear now.