# Akka streams: dealing with futures within graph stage

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Within an akka stream stage `FlowShape[A, B]` , part of the processing I need to do on the A's is to save/query a datastore with a query built with A data. But that datastore driver query gives me a future, and I am not sure how best to deal with it (my main question here).

```
case class Obj(a: String, b: Int, c: String)
case class Foo(myobject: Obj, name: String)
case class Bar(st: String)
//
class SaveAndGetId extends GraphStage[FlowShape[Foo, Bar]] {
 val dao = new DbDao // some dao with an async driver 

 override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes) = new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
  setHandlers(in, out, new InHandler with Outhandler {
   override def onPush() = {
    val foo = grab(in)
    val add = foo.record.value()
    val result: Future[String] = dao.saveAndGetRecord(add.myobject)//saves and returns id as string

   //the naive approach
    val record = Await(result, Duration.inf)
    push(out, Bar(record))// ***tests pass every time

  //mapping the future approach
    result.map { x=>
     push(out, Bar(x))
    } //***tests fail every time
```

The next stage depends on the id of the db record returned from query, but I want to avoid `Await`. I am not sure why mapping approach fails:

```
"it should work" in {
  val source = Source.single(Foo(Obj("hello", 1, "world")))
  val probe = source
    .via(new SaveAndGetId))
    .runWith(TestSink.probe)
  probe
   .request(1)
   .expectBarwithId("one")//say we know this will be
   .expectComplete()
 }
 private implicit class RichTestProbe(probe: Probe[Bar]) {
  def expectBarwithId(expected: String): Probe[Bar] = 
   probe.expectNextChainingPF{
    case r @ Bar(str) if str == expected => r
  }
 }
```

When run with mapping future, I get failure:

```
should work ***FAILED***
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: expected: message matching partial function but got unexpected message OnComplete
at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
at akka.testkit.TestKitBase$class.expectMsgPF(TestKit.scala:406)
at akka.testkit.TestKit.expectMsgPF(TestKit.scala:814)
at akka.stream.testkit.TestSubscriber$ManualProbe.expectEventPF(StreamTestKit.scala:570)
```

The async side channels example in the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/stream/stream-customize.html) has the future in the constructor of the stage, as opposed to building the future within the stage, so doesn't seem to apply to my case.

Comment: You can use `getAsyncCallack`

Comment: I´d use mapAsync. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146418/difference-between-map-and-mapasync this

Answer (score 8):

I agree with Ramon. Constructing a new `FlowShape`is not necessary in this case and it is too complicated. It is very much convenient to use `mapAsync` method here:

Here is a code snippet to utilize `mapAsync`:

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Sink, Source}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

object MapAsyncExample {

  val numOfParallelism: Int = 10

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Source.repeat(5)  
      .mapAsync(parallelism)(x => asyncSquare(x))           
      .runWith(Sink.foreach(println)) previous stage
  }

  //This method returns a Future
  //You can replace this part with your database operations
  def asyncSquare(value: Int): Future[Int] = Future {
    value * value
  }
}
```

In the snippet above, `Source.repeat(5)` is a dummy source to emit `5` indefinitely. There is a sample function `asyncSquare` which takes an `integer` and calculates its square in a `Future`. `.mapAsync(parallelism)(x => asyncSquare(x))` line uses that function and emits the output of `Future` to the next stage. In this snipet, the next stage is a `sink` which prints every item.

`parallelism` is the maximum number of `asyncSquare` calls that can run concurrently.

Answer (score 3):

I think your `GraphStage` is unnecessarily overcomplicated.  The below `Flow` performs the same actions without the need to write a custom stage:

```
val dao = new DbDao

val parallelism = 10 //number of parallel db queries

val SaveAndGetId : Flow[Foo, Bar, _] = 
  Flow[Foo]
    .map(foo => foo.record.value().myobject)
    .mapAsync(parallelism)(rec => dao.saveAndGetRecord(rec))
    .map(Bar.apply)
```

I generally try to treat `GraphStage` as a last resort, there is almost always an idiomatic way of getting the same Flow by using the methods provided by the akka-stream library.